# Selenium Python switch to new window

Tags: python, selenium, window-handles

```
windows_before = driver.window_handles
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2']").click()
windows_after = driver.window_handles
new_window =
driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(windows_before)
```

Please can someone tell me how can I get the id of new window.
I have `windows_before` = `'CDwindow-8b18d716-650e-4793-ac69-10532978004c'`
than I have `list` with id of old and new windows `['CDwindow-8b18d716-650e-4793-ac69-10532978004c', 'CDwindow-1b199b20-c50e-4301-bbea-9f0f8faa2902']`

How can I get the element from my list that not match with `windows_before`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pick the first window in the list that is not `windows_before`, as long as `windows_before` is a string and not a list.

```
new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much
but what means [0] there?

Comment: [0] gets the first item in the list.